# Prove that $N(\tau),V_t,Z_2,\ldots$ are independent in Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

We define a Poisson process is a renewal process in which the interarrival intervals $X_n$'s have an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Denote $N(t)$ is the number of arrivals in $(0,t]$, $S_n$ is the arrival epoch of the $n$th arrival.

Given arbitrary $t>0$. Let $V_t=S_{N(t)+1}-t$, $Z_i=X_{N(t)+i}$ for all $i\ge 2$. It is well-known that $N(t),V_t,Z_2,Z_3,\ldots$ are independent.

My question is how can we prove $N(\tau)$ and $V_t,Z_2,Z_3,\ldots$ are also independent for all $0<\tau\le t$ without using the independent increment property of the Poisson process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the independent increments property, what properties of Poisson processes _are_ you allowed to use? Can what you assert is well-known in your second paragraph be proved _without_ using the independent increments property? If the proof of this well-known fact _requires_ the independent increments property, then what you want to prove must be reduced in scope to $\tau < t$ since the case $\tau=t$ _cannot_ be proved without using the independent increments property: you just proved this yourself by agreeing with the above.

Comment: First I use the following lemma: $$P(t-u<S_k\le t, t<S_{k+1}\le t+v)=\frac{(\lambda t)^k-(\lambda (t-u))^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}\left(1-e^{-\lambda v}\right)$$
Then I calculate the probability $$\begin{aligned} P(V_t\le z_1,Z_2\le z_2,\ldots,Z_m\le z_m)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t)=k,V_t\le z_1,Z_2\le z_2,\ldots,Z_m\le z_m)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t)=k, S_{k+1}-t\le z_1,X_{k+2\le z_2,\ldots,X_{k+m}\le z_m})\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(S_k\le t,t<S_{k+1}\le t+z_1,X_{k+2}\le z_2,\ldots,X_{k+m}\le z_m)\end{aligned}$$
by using the above lemma and the independence of $S_k$ and $X_{k+1},X_{k+2},\ldots$

Comment: That's a proof in an article for the case $t=\tau$

Comment: It seems to me that the (unstated) proof of your lemma does require the use of the independent increments property, but I could be wrong.

Comment: No, the proof for the lemma just uses the independence of $S_k$ and $X_{k+1}$ (if we write $S_{k+1}=S_k+X_{k+1}$ and integrate the joint distribution of $S_k$ and $X_{k+1}$, which is the product of the distribution of $S_k$ and $X_{k+1}$). The integral is quite big but not very hard to calculate. I ask this question because in the article (which contains the above lemma), the author proved the independent increment property quite complicated.